# Dynamically set images (stored in database) as background of ListBox items in ASP.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, image

I have images stored in a SQL Server 2008 database with name. I want to display images with name in ASP.Net ListBox control. Every image has its own unique id. Just want to set images as background to every ListBox Item. I tried too much but failed every time.

Is there any one who can help me?

I will be thankful

Comment: are you able to load the image path normally from the database? What is your problem, setting the list box item background or reading the url of the image from the database. I am not aware of a way to use ASP.NET WebForm listbox overriding its way to render items (usually a text string) defining a custom background picture. You could probably use a repeater for that, or a datalist, why does it have to be a ListBox?

Comment: Including a snippet of relevant code in your question can make it easier for others to understand what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it, and where things might be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a reason why you're using a ListBox, but you'd probably be better off using a ListView instead.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ImageID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='/images/<%#Eval("ImageUrl")%>' />
        <%#Eval("ImageName")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```